# IndexOf and Predicate

Tags: c#, indexof, predicate

```
  public static int IndexOf(Product[] products, Predicate<Product> predicate)
      {
          if (products == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException();
          }
  
          for (int i = 0; i <= products.Length - 1;  i++)
          {
              if (predicate == null)
              {
                  throw new ArgumentNullException();
              }
              Product product = products[i];
              if (predicate(product))
              {
                  return i;
              }
          }
          return -1;
      }
```

1. Searches for the index of a product in an products based on a predicate
   products Products used for searching
   predicate Product predicate
   If match found then returns index of product in products
   otherwise -1
   I am asked to make changes only in the IndexOf(Product[] products, Predict predict) method without touching the Product model.

```
   [Test]
           public void IndexOf_Products_ReturnsTwo()
           {
               var products = new Product[]
               {
                   new Product("Product 1", 10.0d),
                   new Product("Product 2", 20.0d),
                   new Product("Product 3", 30.0d),
               };
               var productToFind = new Product("Product 3", 30.0d);
   
               int index = Utilities.IndexOf(products, product => product.Equals(productToFind));
   
               Assert.That(index, Is.EqualTo(2));
           }
```

2. Expected: 2 But was:-1

```
    public class Product
   {
       public Product(string name, double price)
       {
           Name = name;
           Price = price;
       }
   
       public string Name { get; set; }
   
       public double Price { get; set; }
   
   }
```

Comment: It seems `Product` class doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so you compare b*references*, not *values*

Comment: Side note: this should be called `IndexWhere`, not `IndexOf`.

Comment: That's is not mine project :/ so I can't change the name of method too :(

Comment: That's fine. If nothing else, it's so that you understand that it was poorly named and you can do better when you *do* have control over the name. Naming can be hard, but if you learn better practices from the start, it doesn't have to be hard nearly as often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `IndexOf` is a correct implementation, which can be make to more *general*:

```
  public static int IndexOf<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate)
  {
      if (source is null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
      }

      if (predicate == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
      }
    
      int index = 0;
      
      foreach (T item in source) {
          if (predicate(item))
              return index;

          index += 1;   
      } 

      return -1;
  }
```

The actual problem seems to be with `Product` class which doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.
Without `Equals` and `GetHashCode` .net compare *references* (which are different), not *values*.

To compare by values you should explain .net how to do it, something like this:

```
// Let Product be equatable with Product - IEquatable<Product>
public class Product : IEquatable<Product> {
  ...

  // Let .net know how to compare for equality:
  //TODO: put the right names for Name and Price
  public bool Equals(Product other) => other != null &&
    other.Name == Name &&
    other.Price == Price;

  public override bool Equals(object o) => o is Product other && Equals(other);

  public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(Name, Price);
}
```

**Edit:** if you can't change `Product` class, you have to change `predicate` and explain there how to compare for equality:

```
int index = Utilities
  .IndexOf(products, product => productToFind.Name == product.Name &&
                                productToFind.Price == product.Price);
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1thq75) youself.

Comment: @CerenSusuz: please, fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1thq75

Comment: All solutions solve the problem. Thank you. Can I solve the problem by just making a change in the IndexOf method?

Comment: @CerenSusuz: you can get rid of `Predicate` and hardcode the equality comparison. Another option is not to throw exception on `predicate == null` but use hardcoded comparison in this case